# Layout does not align to center of the parent view

Tags: android, android-view, android-framelayout

Im trying to align a circular image in the middle of two linearlayout with 
different colors, however the view for some reason does not align to the center

but stick to the left, below it I want to place a fragment. any help?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#1b96d9"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#e6e6e6"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/doge"
            app:border_color="#EEEEEE"
            app:border_width="4dp"
            app:shadow="true" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/calendarCard1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:background="#e6e6e6" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use a relative layout instead of so many nested Linear Layout. Using Relative layouts are easy and efficient. Check this http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-relativelayout-example/ for understanding the relative layouts

Comment: Because using a relative layout also does not work, plus you cant create a "weight-dependent" view using relative layout but only using linearlayout.

Answer (score 0):

Your circular image layout is inside a `FrameLayout` along with the `LinearLayout`.  `FrameLayout` basically puts all its children one atop another.

Comment: Not correct replace the "com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView" with a regular ImageView and you will see it place it in the middle of the top section.